# Storing array in one field Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is some question: I'm making design of the database, and there is "restaurants" table; this table has field "food_type". This field may store 1 or 2, 3, ... values which are describes types of food in this restaurant (Spanish, French, Italian, etc). If I understand right I should store array of codes in this field (0=>French, 1=>Italian, ...), and I need to have table "food_types" with 'id', 'name'. But there is another problem: some of my view should show all food types, and my app uses internationalization, therefore I should store names of types in yml file for using I18n in Rails and I shouldn't use 'name' column in "food_types" instead of it. Please, tell me, what is the best solution for my problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should introduce a [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) association, like this:

```
#app/models/restaurant.rb
has_many :restaurant_food_types
has_many :food_types, :through => :restaurant_food_types

#app/models/restaurant_food_type.rb
Class RestaurantFoodType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
    belongs_to :food_type
end

#app/models/food_type.rb
has_many :restaurant_food_types
has_many :restaurants, :through => :restaurant_food_types
```

The DB for the `restaurant_food_type` join model could look like this:

```
restaurant_food_types
  id 
  restaurant_id
  food_type_id
```